# Encoding video for streaming with multiple subtitle streams in VLC

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc, subtitle

I am implementing an offline video streaming service, so our users can have the encrypted videos on their computers and open them only by using our streaming app.

So what I need is to stream a freshly decrypted video file directly to a local VLC client so I don't have to save it on disk. A minimum working example would be:

```
cat my_video.mp4 | vlc -
```

But this only shows the video and audio tracks, no subtitles.

I want to know if there is a way to encode a video so that this would work with 3 audio tracks and 3 subtitle tracks.
I would also settle for an answer explaining that it is not possible and why not.

More details below:

---

I have 3 audio tracks and 3 subtitle tracks and I am using FFMPEG.
(The original format of the videos is mp4 with an h264 encoding)

Currently, I am able to make streamable `.mp4` files, [thanks to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/438471/338990), and also to make `.ts` files that will show the video and the 3 audio options but not the subtitles. The command I am using is this:

```
video_name=demo_0101.mp4
sub_name=demo_0101.srt
output=0101.mp4 # Or `.ts`

ffmpeg\
  -i en_raw/$video_name -i pt_raw/$video_name -i es_raw/$video_name\
  -i en_subs/$sub_name\
  -i pt_subs/$sub_name\
  -i es_subs/$sub_name\
  -map 2:v\
  -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0\
  -map 3:s -map 4:s -map 5:s\
  -c:v libx264 -crf 22\
  -movflags faststart\ # (This line is only necessary for .mp4)
  -c:a:0 aac -c:a:1 aac -c:a:2 aac\
  -c:s:0 mov_text -c:s:1 mov_text -c:s:2 mov_text\
  $output
```

The problem is: The subtitles are not recognized (don't show up at all) using the `.ts` format and when using `.mp4` VLC reports an error:

> Unidentified codec:
>   VLC could not identify the audio or video codec

Please note when not streaming the `.mp4` version works with all audios and the subtitles, i.e.:

```
vlc my_video.mp4
```

---

In case someone is wondering I plan on selecting the which subtitle and audio to play from command line with the VLC options: `--audio-track 1 --sub-track 0`

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to encode the subtitles directly on the video which would be the preferable solution. However, I found a VLC command that will display the subtitle file together with the streaming video:

```
cat 0101.mp4 | vlc --sub-file en_subs/demo_0101.srt
```

This is not ideal for 2 reasons:

1. It does not work with the `.ts` format only `.mp4`.
2. This requires me to save the original subtitle files on the user disk.

I will not mark this solution as the accepted answer because if it is possible to stream the video directly with the subtitles I want to know, and I also believe that such answer would be helpful for others that happen to read this page.